# better xpath from elements in XPath-1.0

Tags: xml, xpath

is there another / better way to do this?
It has to be this structure, I can't change.

```
<xml>
   <animal house="1">
     <home>Cat</home>
     <home>Dog</home>
     <outside>Dove</outside>
     <outside>Parrot</outside>
   </animal>
   <animal house="2">
     <home>Turtle</home>
     <home>Snake</home>
     <outside>Bee</outside>
     <outside>Horse</outside>
   </animal>
</xml>
```

now I need to get from all houses the house animals and join the values

This works, but I would like to know if is there other way to do it using xpath

http://xsltransform.net/3MEbY7g

```
<xsl:for-each select="./animal">
    <xsl:variable name="temp" >
        <xsl:copy-of select="./home"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$temp"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible using XPath-2.0 or above. So try this XPath-2.0 expression:

```
string-join(for $a in /xml/animal return $a/home/text(),' - ')
```

Its output is

```
Cat - Dog - Turtle - Snake
```

The last part of the XPath expression is the delimiter.

---

In XPath-1.0 you cannot achieve this. The mere set you can select is

```
/xml/animal/home
```

which selects all 'animals at home'.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, it has to be in XPath-1.0

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
<xsl:for-each select="./animal">
    <xsl:variable name="temp" >
        <xsl:copy-of select="./home"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$temp"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

(a) is very long-winded, and (b) doesn't produce the required output under XSLT 1.0.

In XSLT 1.0 you can get the required output using

```
<xsl:for-each select="animal/home">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and in XSLT 2.0 you can write:

```
<xsl:value-of select="animal/home" separator=""/>
```

The same result can be achieved with a single XPath 2.0 expression:

```
string-join(/*/animal/home, "")
```

But there is no XPath 1.0 equivalent.